# Counting eleven digit  integers with the sum of the digits 2

Tags: combinatorics

**Suppose n is an integer, such that the sum of the digits of n is 2, and $10^{10} \lt n \lt 10^{11} $. The number of different values for n is:**

Let me try to list them :

```
(1) 11000000000
(2) 10100000000
(3) 10010000000
...
(10)10000000001
```

So I am getting 10 possible values but the answer is 11.What  am I missing here ?

EDIT: I was missing 20000000000.

Comment: 20,000,000,000?

Comment: Your new question doesn't make sense. Also, it seems better to start a new question instead of replacing an existing one.

Comment: @ Yuval Filmus : Fixed.

Comment: The question should not be marked as unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the OP's edit, to remove this from the unanswered question list, the 11th entry is 20,000,000,000.

Comment: Thanks,+1 and accepted.:-)

Comment: Thanks for the points. I've been trolling the unanswered questions.